# How to expand HTML elements and scrape td elements from table schemas?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a website that requires a user to click on an object, expand it, and then the schema of the table will be revealed.  This is for Google BigQuery; everything is web-based.  The relevant HTML, and and all tag, looks like this.

```
<div class="p6n-dynamic-tree-node-wrapper layout-row flex" tabindex="-1" role="treeitem" aria-expanded="false" ng-focus="treeCtrl.handleNgFocus($index)" ng-blur="treeCtrl.handleNgBlur($index)" ng-keydown="treeCtrl.handleKeyPress($event, $index, node)" ng-click="treeCtrl.handleNodeClick(node)" flex="" layout="row" jslog="47815;track:generic_click"> <!----> <span class="p6n-dynamic-tree-node-content" style="padding-left: 56px;"> <span class="p6n-dynamic-tree-fixed-icon-width"> <!----> <!----> </span> <span ng-transclude="" class="p6n-dynamic-tree-transclude-span"> <!----><pan-icon class="p6n-bq-tree-node-icon flex-none" flex="none" ng-if="node.icon" size="18" icon="table">
            <div class="p6n-icon p6n-icon-18 p6n-icon-table">
              <!---->
              <!----><md-icon ng-if="icon != 'working'" class="" md-svg-icon="icon-18:table" ng-attr-aria-label="{{innerAriaLabel === null ?
                                        undefined :
                                        innerAriaLabel || icon}}" role="img" aria-label="table"><svg id="table_cache57" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 18 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false"><path d="M2 2h14v14H2V2zm2 6v2h2V8H4zm0-4v2h10V4H4zm0 8v2h2v-2H4zm4-4v2h2V8H8zm4 0v2h2V8h-2zm-4 4v2h2v-2H8zm4 0v2h2v-2h-2z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></md-icon><!---->
            </div></pan-icon><!----> <span class="p6n-ellipsis flex" flex=""> tickets </span> <!----> </span> </span> </div>
```

After the table is expanded, by a click event, the table schema is revealed, and everything is under tables, with td elements, like this:

```
<tr pan-table-row="" ng-repeat="field in ctrl.flatSchema | panSortBy:(sortCtrl&amp;&amp;sortCtrl.getActiveKey()):&quot;normal&quot;:sortCache:paginateCtrl  track by field.fullName" ng-init="$last &amp;&amp; panTableCtrl.onRowRepeatEnd()" pan-table-row-after-repeat="field"><!----><!----> <td ng-class="{'p6n-bq-table-schema-clickable-field-name': ctrl.areFieldsClickable()}" ng-click="ctrl.onFieldClick(field)" role="button" tabindex="0" class="p6n-bq-table-schema-clickable-field-name"> <span class="p6n-color-secondary"></span><b class="p6n-color-primary">submitter_id</b></td> <td>INTEGER</td> <td>NULLABLE</td> <!----><td ng-if="ctrl.showDescription()"></td><!----> </tr>
```

So, my question is, based on the description above, is there a way to expand all web-based tables, expand each, and scrape info from td elements of each table schema?  Thanks for the look.

Comment: You can use web drivers like selenium to expand it by click events and get the tag out of it.

Comment: You can use web drivers like selenium to expand it by click events and get the tag out of it.

Comment: Can you share a link to the site in question?